# Differentiating between slashes in a string using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

A program that I'm writing (in Java) gets input data made up of three kinds of parts, separated by a slash `/`. The parts can be one of the following:

1. A *name* matching the regular expression `\w*`
2. A *call* matching the expression `\w*\(.*\)`
3. A *path* matching the expression `<.*>|\".*\"`. A *path* can contain slashes.

An example string could look like this:

```
bar/foo()/foo(bar)/<foo/bar>/bar/"foo/bar"/foo()
```

which has the following structure

```
name/call/call/path/name/path/call
```

I want to split this string into parts, and I'm trying to do this using a regular expression. My current expression captures slashes after *calls* and *paths*, but I'm having trouble getting it to capture slashes after *names* without also including slashes that may exist within paths. My current expression, just capturing slashes after *paths* and *calls* looks like this:

```
(?<=[\)>\"])/
```

How can I expand this expression to also capture slashes after *names* without including slashes within *paths*?

Comment: It would be tremendously helpful if you also said what your regex match should contain for your sample string, exactly.

Comment: @Tomalak I want to capture the *slashes* in between the parts, so that I can split the string on them.

Comment: If you use my suggested expression, then there is no need to split the string - just use the matches. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah, I realised that when I read yours and aiobe's answers. That just proves the value of asking for other people's opinions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(\w+|\w+\([^/]*\)(?:/\w+\([^/]*\))*|<[^>]*>|"[^"]*")(?=/|$)
```

captures this from the string `'bar/foo()/foo(bar)/<foo/bar>/bar/"foo/bar"/foo()'`

- `'bar'`
- `'foo()/foo(bar)'`
- `'<foo/bar>'`
- `'bar'`
- `'"foo/bar"'`
- `'foo()'`

It does *not* capture the separating slashes, though (what for? - just assume they are there).

The simpler `(\w+|\w+\([^/]*\)|<[^>]*>|"[^"]*")(?=/|$)` would capture calls separately:

- `"foo()"`
- `"foo(bar)"`

---

EDIT: Usually, I do a regex breakdown:

```
(           # begin group 1 (for alternation)
  \w+       #   at least one word character
|           # or...
  \w+       #   at least one word character
  \(        #   a literal "("
  [^/]*     #   anything but a "/", as often as possible
  \)        #   a literal ")"
|           # or...
  <         #   a "<"
  [^>]*     #   anything but a ">", as often as possible
  >         #   a ">"
|           # or...
  "         #   a '"'
  [^"]*     #   anything but a '"', as often as possible
  "         #   a '"'
)           # end group 1
(?=/|$)     # look-ahead: ...followed by a slash or the end of string
```

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was to match slashes with an even number of quotes to the left of it. (I.e., having a positive look behind of something like `(".*")*` but this ends up in an exception saying

```
Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length
```

Honestly I think you'd be better of with a `Matcher`, using an or:ed together version of your components, (something like `\w*|\w*\(.*\)|(<.*>|\".*\")`) and do `while (matcher.find())`.

Answer (score 3):

Having your deliminator for your string not escaped when used inside your input might not be the best choice. However, you do have the luxury of the "false" slash being inside a regular pattern. What I suggest...

1. Split the whole string on "/"
2. Parse each part until you get to the start of the path
3. Put the path elements into a list until the end of the path
4. Rejoin the path back on "/"

I highly recommend you consider escaping the "/" in your paths to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern captures all parts of your example string separately without including the delimiter into the results:

```
\w+\(.*?\)|<.*>|\".*\"|\w+
```